# Any way to animate this? A HTML game I'm making

Tags: javascript, html, css

I started making a HTML roguelike, and want some animations to be working. Any way to make a character slide, not just teleport there? Everything is made of divs.
[image]
Here's the code I'm using:

```
function keypress(e){ //tbd
var x = e.which || e.keyCode;
if (input){
    if (x==37){ //left
        nexttile = [
            [parseInt(charpos[0])],
            [parseInt(charpos[1]) - 1],
        ]
        if ( canPassthrough(map[nexttile[0]][nexttile[1]]) ) charpos[1]--;
        else return 0;

    }
    else if(x==38){ //up
        nexttile = [
            [parseInt(charpos[0]) - 1],
            [parseInt(charpos[1])],
        ];
        if ( canPassthrough(map[nexttile[0]][nexttile[1]]) ) charpos[0]--;
        else return 0;

    }
    else if(x==39){ //right

        nexttile = [
            [parseInt(charpos[0])],
            [parseInt(charpos[1]) + 1],
        ];
        if ( canPassthrough(map[nexttile[0]][nexttile[1]]) ) charpos[1]++;
        else return 0;
    }
    else if(x==40){ //down
        nexttile = [
            [parseInt(charpos[0]) + 1],
            [parseInt(charpos[1])],
        ];
        if ( canPassthrough(map[nexttile[0]][nexttile[1]]) ) charpos[0]++;
        else return 0;
    }
    updatehero();

    }
}
function canPassthrough(t){
    if ((t!=1)&&(t!=0)&&(typeof t !== 'undefined')){
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}

function updatehero(){
    screen = document.getElementById("game-field");
    oldchar = document.getElementById("hero");
    if (oldchar) screen.removeChild(oldchar);   
    heromod = document.createElement("div");
    heromod.id = "hero";
    heromod.style.width = tilescale;
    heromod.style.height = tilescale;
    heromod.style.left = charpos[1]*parseInt(tilescale) + "px";
    heromod.style.top = charpos[0]*parseInt(tilescale) + "px";

    screen.appendChild(heromod);

    centerchar();
}
```

This is Javascript code I'm using for very basic character movement.
Here's CSS of the "@" div:

```
#hero {
    position: absolute;
    background-size: contain;
    background-image: url(../img/charplaceholder.png);
}
#hero:after{
    content: "0";
    color: transparent;

}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Could you paste  your code on fiddle

Comment: You can try applying a CSS transition to the element that you want to be smooth. Just do something like.... `transition:all .5s ease;` don't forget to add vendor prefixes. Google CSS transitions for more info.

Comment: @ManProgrammer There's too much to paste, I provided basic functions for you.

Comment: @www139 I'm not sure this will work, the way updatehero() function works it removes the old character div and pastes a new one.

Comment: This is tough. Are you using pixel positioning of the #hero div in JavaScript? If so, why not just change the style property for the left and top and add a CSS transition?

Comment: @www139, yeah, alright, however what transition should I add?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Transitions/Using_CSS_transitions

Comment: Posted my answer, try it and see if it works ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding a CSS transition to the div. A CSS transition applies new style(s) over the period of time specified. You can do `transition:all .5s ease;` which means that **any** new styles applied will be applied over a period of time or you can give the property name like this `transition:left .5s ease;`. Here is some code for you.

```
#hero {
    position: absolute;
    background-size: contain;
    background-image: url(../img/charplaceholder.png);

    /*do these for single properties*/        
    -o-transition:left .5s ease;
    -moz-transition:left .5s ease;
    -webkit-transition:left .5s ease;
    -ms-transition:left .5s ease;

    -o-transition:left .5s ease;
    -moz-transition:left .5s ease;
    -webkit-transition:left .5s ease;
    -ms-transition:left .5s ease;

    /*do this code for transitions for all properties*/
    -o-transition:all .5s ease;
    -moz-transition:all .5s ease;
    -webkit-transition:all .5s ease;
    -ms-transition:all .5s ease;
    transition:all .5s ease;
}
```

Comment: Works great! Can you explain a little when the animations trigger and if there's a way to trigger it from js code?

Comment: Transitions work for inline style manipulation in JavaScript as well as CSS pseudo classes like a:hover. Just change the inline style with Javascript (like you are likely already doing) like this elem.style.left = x+'px'; (x is an integer).